# Verizon 4G broadband

Tags: wireless-networking

We have a 4G Wireless Broadband by Verizon.  It was originally set up for our office computers but we just purchased a new HP with Windows 7 and it will not recognize it.  What do I do?

Comment: What have you even tried?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the VZAccess Manager software, which includes the driver for your particular mobile broadband device.  If you do not have the CD that came with your device, you can download the software from http://www.vzam.net/download/